# Vertices that are K away

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Given a graph **G(V,E)** and a vertex **v**, how do i find all the vertices that are reachable via simple paths ( no vertex on the path repeats) of length exactly **k**.

Powers of adjacency matrix gives the number of paths between vertices but it includes non simple paths.

Is this problem solvable in polynomial time ? If not are there any known approximation algorithms. Any pointers to literature would be great.

Comment: This is a fascinating question that I think belongs on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Is it possible to move the question between different stack sites ? I may not have enough reputation to do this.

Comment: Somebody can do it, but as far as I can tell, I don't have enough reputation to do it either. :-/

Comment: assume you have a triangle formed by v, A, and B. With k=2, are both A and B what you are looking for?

Comment: @JameySharp, no it does not, please read the FAQ of the sites before making suggestions about migration. This questions should not be migrated to cstheory, but to [cs.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering only the first question: "is it solvable in polynomial time?".

Suppose it is solvable in polynomial time. Then solve it for `k=|V|-1` and pick any resulting vertex. Remove this vertex and solve this problem for `k=|V|-2`. Resulting set of vertices should contain at least one vertex that was connected to the last removed vertex. Remove this vertex and continue process for `k=|V|-i` until single starting vertex remains. You've just found a [Hamiltonian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) for the original graph with polynomial time algorithm.

Since Hamiltonian path problem is NP-complete, the problem in OP is also very unlikely to be solvable in polynomial time.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm presented below will find a list of nodes that have minimum distance equal to `k` from a starting node `v`. EG: Given a triangle graph v, A, and B if:

- `k` is 0, then result is `v`
- `k` is 1, then result contains `A` and `B`
- `k` is 2 or more, then result is `empty`

Pseudocode:

```
FindNodesWithShortestPath_K(G, v, k):
    create empty list R
    create empty queue Q

    mark v as visited
    set v.distance to 0
    add v to Q

    while Q is not empty:
        t <- dequeue node from Q
        if t.distance == k:
            add t to R
        else if t.distance > k:
            break
        else                
            for all neighbors u of t:
                if u is not marked as visited:
                    mark u as visited
                    u.distance = t.distance + 1
                    enqueue u onto Q

    return result
```

NOTE:

- Checking if node are marked as visited guarantees simple paths
- The initial distance of the nodes is not relevant
- if t.distance == k, then t belongs to R and t neighbors (not alredy in Q) do not
- if t.distance > k, then the algorithm stops even if Q is not empty. Given the algorithm implementation, the distance of the nodes in Q is non decreasing
- Operations over R and Q can run in O(1) depending on the implementation. The algorithm has a worst case scenario of O(|E| + |V|)

Comment: This is a bfs starting from the vertex v.

Comment: pretty much, the termination condition is of course different. Does this solve your problem? Did I interpret your question correctly?

Comment: no it doesn't. I want the vertices that are reachable in "exactly" k steps via simple paths.